# Gervill for Oracle Java?

Tags: audio, javasound, java, gervill

[Gervill](https://gervill.dev.java.net/) is said to be created for the opensource JDK but is it compatible for Oracle Java?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just make sure you have `gervill.jar` on your classpath.

Comment: So where are the tutorial, it is so hard to find a simple step to load SF2